# Angular communication between two components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components

I'm building a simple web based application using angular version 6.

In my application there is a component which has a child component. There is a function in this component(In the parent component, not the child component.) and I want to invoke that function using a button which is in the child component.

This image explains the format of my components.

[image]

I think its regarding to angular `@Output`. But i can't manage it.

This is how my code has organized.

## Parent Component - component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-teacher-home',
  templateUrl: './teacher-home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teacher-home.component.scss']
})
export class TeacherHomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  formView: boolean = false;

  toggleForm(){
    this.formView = !this.formView;
  }
}
```

## Parent component - component.html file

```
<div>
    <child-compnent></child-compnent>
</div>
```

## Child component - component.html file

```
<div>
    <button>Toggle Form view</button>
</div>
```

i want to callthe function `toggleForm()` of parent component when the button clicked which is in child component.

Comment: Check _Angular_ documentation, specifically section on [Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). Also, do some research before asking, a single search would have returned bunch of answers that cover your use case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

read this article: [Understanding @Output and EventEmitter in Angular](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular)

child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<button (click)="sendToParent('hi')" >sendToParent</button> `
})
export class AppChildComponent {
  @Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter;

  sendToParent(name){
    this.childToParent.emit(name);
  }
}
```

parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  toggle(){
    console.log('toggle')
  }

}
```

parent html:

```
<app-child (childToParent)="toggle($event)"></app-child>
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-rpvw8w)

Comment: when i create that @Output emitter it gives an error in <any> "expected 0 type arguments but got 1"

Comment: try ```@Output() childToParent = new EventEmitter;```

Comment: i'm using angular 6

Comment: its worked.. thank you very much... i'm really appreciate your help

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of ways to do this :

1. Is to create an event inside the child component and then give it a callback, something like this:

   `@Output('eventName') buttonPressed = new EventEmitter();`

and call `buttonPressed.emit()`  when you want the event to be triggered

on the parent side it will look like this :

```
<div>
    <child-compnent (eventName)="toggleForm()"></child-compnent>
</div>
```

2. Another way is to create a shared service that will contain the shared functions and data for both components

Comment: its worked.. thank you very much... i'm really appreciate your help

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `@Output` decorator inside your child component and **emit** an event when the button present clicked inside your child.

For eg: -

**Child component.html**

```
<div>
    <button (click)="childButtonClicked()">Toggle Form view</button>
</div>
```

**Child component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output triggerToggle: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  ...
   childButtonClicked() {
     this.triggerToggle.emit(true);
   }
  ...
}
```

**Parent Component**

```
<div>
    <child-compnent (triggerToggle)="toggleForm()"></child-compnent>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `EventEmitter` of angular to listen to events from your child component.

**parent.component.ts**

```
toggleForm($event) {}
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<div>
    <child-compnent  (trigger)="toggleForm($event)" ></child-compnent>
</div>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Output() trigger : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

buttonClick(){
  this.trigger.emit('click');
}
```